# 2 PHP Imagick codes into one

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am trying to integrate two small Imagick codes into one. The first code splits a sentence into words, then them into images. The second code appends these images, making a whole image-based sentence. In the first code, I save individual word-based-images in a directory, which is then fetched by the second code using PHP's globe function. Now, I do not want to write images in the directory, instead I supply them to the second code in run-time and append. I need an idea how to do that. I am thinking about Clone() function, building an image index, but I am not sure about that and I need your feedback.

```
     // First Code

     $text = "Some sample senetnces";  
     $words  = explode(' ', $text);

     $imageout = new \Imagick();

     foreach ($words as $no => $word)
     {

     $draw = new \ImagickDraw();
    # $draw->setStrokeColor($strokeColor);
    $draw->setFillColor('black');

    # $draw->setStrokeWidth(2);
    $draw->setFontSize(36);

    $draw->setFont(DOCROOT . "/Congenial-Bold.ttf");
    $draw->annotation(50, 50, $word);

    $imagick = new \Imagick();
    $imagick->newImage(500, 300, 'DeepSkyBlue');
    $imagick->setImageFormat("png");
    $imagick->drawImage($draw);
    $imagick->trimImage(0);
    $imagick->setImageBackgroundColor('DeepSkyBlue'); 
    $imagick->spliceImage(10, 0, $imagick->getImageWidth(), $imagick->getImageHeight());
    $imagick->writeImage(DOCROOT . '/tem634/fonts-' . $no . '.png');
    # $images[] = $imagick->Clone();

    }


    // Second Code

    $images = glob( DOCROOT . "/tem634/*.png");
    $canvas = new Imagick();

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $im = new Imagick($image);
        $canvas->addImage($im);
    }

    // append the images into one
    $canvas->resetIterator();
    $combined = $canvas->appendImages(false);
    $combined->setImageformat("png"); 
    $combined->writeImage(DOCROOT . '/append.png');
```

Comment: How about showing us what it produces?